# lombok annotations are not identified by junit in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, lombok

In my project, there are few lombok annotations being used. I can build the project with maven without any hassle, but when I try to run a unit test file in Intellij, it fails with 'cannot find symbol' error for lombok annotations. I have tried few suggestions from old posts like enabling annotation processing but still no luck.

Any idea to resolve this?

Note: lombok plugin is installed in Intellij. lombok dependency is there in pom file. Intellij version is 2020.3.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you have lombok plugin which is bundled not the one you have installed yourself. Also, what is the version of lombok dependency you are using?

Comment: @code_mechanic Thanks for reaching. Yes I have installed the bundled lombok plugin with Intellij Settings->Plugins->Marketplace. And the lombok dependency version is 1.16.18.

<lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: @code_mechanic I have tried once changing the version to 1.18.18 as well.

Comment: " Yes I have installed the bundled lombok plugin with Intellij" - You don't need to install it comes with intelij now, if you have two lombok plugin then uninstall other, dependency version greater than 1.18 should work

Comment: Mmm.. I initially had an earlier version of Intellij and I installed the lombok plugin that time. Now I have updated the version and seems it has the bundled plugin as you mentioned. However I have only one plugin installed under plugins and it is the bundled one. When I changed the version to 1.18.18 even my maven build also failed which is working currently. Is there anything more to do after changing the version?

Comment: It would be better if you post your pom.xml file, because this should work, If nothing working out then I would suggest installing latest intelij again (if that is an option) and delete existing one with it files, I remember having same issue 3-4 months back when this version and bundle lombok thing came out and at that time it was persisting issue so may be you have hit the same issue.

Comment: This was the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257311) I logged with Jetbrains, but in my case the bundled plugin was missing and I did the similar steps you have done.

Comment: @code_mechanic Thanks for the valuable comments. I will try out and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Please update to the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA available: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion. In case the issue is still present, please share the sample project in the issue created in: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Thanks

Comment: @code_mechanic I have uninstalled Intellij and deleted all files related to it. Then I installed the latest version and try running unit tests, but issue is still there. When I changed the lombok version to 1.18.18, even my maven build is getting failed. But with 1.16.18, maven build is successful even though running unit test failed. Is there something with the JDK version? I'm using Java 1.6.

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please refer my last comment above and share your thoughts?

Comment: @ShehanCharuka check some of the suggestions given [here](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/988), may be that resolves your issues :)

Comment: @code_mechanic Seems the problem is with Java version. When I changed the version to Java 8, this particular error disappeared but errors coming from different Java code snippets. Thanks for the guidance given. For the moment I don't have a solution. Will check for some more alternatives.