# Running junit tests in Intellij with Java 6 & lombok annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, lombok

Could someone please suggest me the required Intellij Idea setup to run a junit test refers to lombok annotations with Java 1.6.

My current setup:-

Intellij Version - 2020.3.3 with built-in lombok plugin

lombok dependency version - 1.16.18

My previous question on the issue:-
[lombok annotations are not identified by junit in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031356/lombok-annotations-are-not-identified-by-junit-in-intellij?noredirect=1#comment118538883_67031356)

I can build the project with maven but cannot run unit test with Intellij. When I changed to Java 8 and try to run unit tests, lombok error disappeared, but failed since project is not compatible with Java 8.
Therefore I'm looking for the ideal Intellij setup that works for this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find a lombok version which works with Java 6. Then find the release date of that lombok version. Then download an old version of Intellij Idea whose release date is around the lombok release date.

Comment: Can you please share the code sample? Thank you

Comment: @yejianfengblue Thank you for the valuable comment. I have tried with Intellij 2016.3.8 and 2016.2.5 still no luck. Highly appreciate if you could also check my previous question (link in post) and see if you have any different thoughts.

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Thanks for reaching. I will share the code blocks relevant to the error.

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Thanks for reaching. I will share the code blocks relevant to the error.

I have a class called UserInfo with couple of lombok annotations.

Note:Additional @ signs not allowed. Hence using [At]
[At]lombok.Builder
[At]lombok.Data
[At]JsonDeserialize(using = UserInfoDeserializer.class)
public class UserInfo {

Error is thrown from UserInfoDeserializer where this is being imported.

import xxxx.UserInfo;
import xxxx.UserInfo.UserInfoBuilder;

public class UserInfoDeserializer

Error:-
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class UserInfoBuilder

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Apologies. Seems new lines are ignored in comments.

Comment: What are the dependencies for `JsonDeserializer` and `UserInfoDeserializer`? It would really help if you create an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue attaching the project sample to it. Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho are referring to the imports?